# Part of hair children is missing

Tags: particles, hair

I have this bird model with hair particles.

All the hair is looking okay except this bit on the left.
The hair particles are going outwards but the linked children seem to go inwards or something.

The normals are correct. Im using mirror modifier with use modifier stack enabled.

any guesses?

[image]
[image]
[image]